# Почему firstChild выводит соседа?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть задача:

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Животные
      <ul>
        <li>Млекопитающие
          <ul>
            <li>Коровы</li>
            <li>Ослы</li>
            <li>Собаки</li>
            <li>Тигры</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Другие
          <ul>
            <li>Змеи</li>
            <li>Птицы</li>
            <li>Ящерицы</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Рыбы
      <ul>
        <li>Аквариумные
          <ul>
            <li>Гуппи</li>
            <li>Рыба-ангел</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Морские
          <ul>
            <li>Морская форель</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    for (let li of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
      // получаем название из текстового узла
      let title = li.firstChild.data;

      title = title.trim(); // удаляем лишние пробелы c конца строки

      // считаем количество потомков
      let count = li.getElementsByTagName('li').length;

      console.log(title + ': ' + count);
    }
  </script>



</body>
```

Почему выводятся эти данные:

```
Коровы
Ослы
Собаки
Тигры
```

Или более упрощенный вариант вопроса.
Есть иерархия:

```
1 
 2
  3
  3
```

Мы можем вывести 2, так как он первый ребенок 1 и первую тройку, так как она ребенок 2. Но почему выведется и вторая тройка?

Comment: Вы ищите все li на странице. Т.е. и более высокого уровня(Животные, Млекопитающие) и более низкого(Коровы, Рыбы)

Answer (score 1):

У вас цикл по всем найденным элементам `<li>`.
`for (let li of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {...`

Comment: А это строка? 
`let title = li.firstChild.data;` Мы нашли Коров по вашему циклу в ответе, но у них нет firstChild, у них он null.

Comment: Я кажется понял, дело в том, что firstChild находит текст... как первый элемент. Немного перепутал с children, которые ищут только элементы-узлы, а не текстовые-узлы и комменты-узлы.

Comment: @NickRoddy почти правильно. Только не текст, а TextNode